# Discord bot Error Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

Do anyone know the problem at this javascript bot?

The window (Start.bat) just open and close. Main error is at line 100 - 115!
I use it on my discord server and i need a bot to ban words. The bot is edited to ban words, but now it don't work. (Line 100 - 115)
I hope someone knows the problem.

It is made for a bot named The parrot, and i need a working code.

### Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
var fs = require("fs");
var oldAuthor;

// ADD YOUR BOT'S TOKEN HERE
const token = " *censored* ";

bot.on('ready', () => {
  
});

bot.on('message', message => {
 // Makes sure the first word is ~createcommand
 var checkMessage = message.content.split(" ");
 if(checkMessage[0] == "~lagkommando")
 {
  // commandText gets grabbed by splitting the string with |
  // commandName gets grabbed by splitting the string with spaces
  // command Name must have '~' in it just so you can't use any word you
  // want
  var commandText = message.content.split("|",2);
  var commandName = message.content.split(" ");
  if(commandName[1].charAt(0) == "~")
   {
    checkExistingCommand(commandText,commandName);
    message.channel.sendMessage("Command " + commandName[1] + " has been created");
   } else {
    message.channel.sendMessage("Command must contain '~'");
   }
 }

 /*
  * Checks the commands.txt file to see if anyone posted the command.
  * commands.txt is split with semi-colons. For loop to check every single
  * command. If there is a match, then it opens up the txt file associate
  * with that command. If there are multiple pictures then the user should
  * type $random{} and then type in all the pictures in the brackets
  * separated by semi-colons. If there is no $random{} then it just sends the
  * message.
  */
 fs.readFile('./commands/commands.txt','utf8',function(err,f){
  var com = f.toString().split(";");
  for(i = 0; i < com.length; i++)
  {
   if(message.content == com[i])
   {
    if(com[i] == "~commands")
     {
      message.channel.sendMessage(com);
      break;
     }
    if(com[i] == "~help")
     {
      message.channel.sendMessage("Kommandoer: ~help, ~commands, ~database, ~Hei, ~memes og ~problem");
      break;
     }
    var command = "./commands/" + com[i] + ".txt";
    fs.readFile(command,'utf8', function(err,f){
    try{
     var com2 = f.toString().split(";");
     var num = Math.random() * ((com2.length - 1) - 0) + 0;
     message.channel.sendMessage(com2[Math.floor(num)]);
    }
    catch(err) {
     console.error("",err);
    }
    });
   }
  }
 });
  
});

function checkExistingCommand(commandText,commandName)
{
 var com = commandName[1];
 var desc = commandText[1];
 var CE = false;
 fs.readFile('./commands/commands.txt','utf8',function(err,f){
  var findCommands = f.toString().split(";");
  for(i = 0; i < findCommands.length; i++)
  {
   if(com == findCommands[i])
   {
    CE = true;
   }
  }
  if(CE == true)
  {
   createCommand(desc,true,com);
  } else if (CE == false)
  {
   createCommand(desc,false,com);
  }
 });
 
}

bot.on('message', message => { 

    var sender = message.author;
    var msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    var prefix = '>'

    if (sender.id === ' *Censored* ') { 
    return;
    }

    if (msg.includes('noob')) {
        message.delete();
        message.author.send('The word noob is banned, next time YOU can be banned! ')
    }

}

// Appends and/or creates the text files.
function createCommand(desc,b,com)
{
 var fileName = "./commands/" + com + ".txt";
 if(b == true)
 {
  fs.writeFile(fileName,desc,function(err){
  if(err) {
   return console.error(err);
  }
  });
 } else if (b == false){
  fs.appendFile('./commands/commands.txt',com+';',(err) =>
  {
  if(err) throw err;
  });
  
  fs.writeFile(fileName,desc,function(err){
  if(err) {
   return console.error(err);
  }
  });
 }
 return;
}

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Add "pause>nul" to the last line of your Start.bat to see the error.

Comment: like this?  "node "run.js" pause>nul"

Comment: Sorry, I meant make a new line at the bottom with nothing on it but pause>Nul

Comment: This is the text that comes up.                                                 SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9) How to i read it, so i can re-code the bot?

Answer (score 2):

I see that you need a better text editor.

On Line 115. (At the eventhandler for message recieved for your `Client`). You were missing your closing line of `);`.

Also, just in case you did not knew, I realised that you made your `msg` string variable to upper-case before you compared it to a lower-cased string for commands.
 Do note that `includes()` method is case-sensitive.

I am using Visual Studio Code for my text editor. If somehow it does not show you syntax highlighting and stuff, check the bottom right of the editor, it should display Javascript there.
 [image]
If it does not, change it to Javascript and it should show the syntax highlighting and stuff correctly.

Comment: Now, at the Visual studio code it sais ----------------- ')' expected. (154, 17)---- and--- ',' expected. (154,1) --- and ',' expected. (129, 1)

Comment: i fixed that problem... but now it sais "events.js:216
    throw new TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');
    ^"